# How do I query an array in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I want to create user permissions management. I use TypeORM with PostgreSQL. This is the column definition for the permissions within the user entity:

```
@Column({
  type: 'text',
  array: true
})
permissions: UserPermission[] = [];
```

This is the `UserPermission` enum:

```
export enum UserPermission {
  APP_USER = 'APP_USER',
  USER_ADMIN = 'USER_ADMIN',
  SUPERADMIN = 'SUPERADMIN'
}
```

I want to find one user who has the `'SUPERADMIN'` permission but I cannot find the right spot in the documentation / github issues which explains how to do this. I already spent over an hour on this and I suppose this is a simple task.

Is there something like "Includes" to check if the permissions array includes a specific element and/or includes multiple elements?

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    permissions: Includes('SUPERADMIN')
  }
});
```

I would be very thankful if someone could point me to the correct documentation page :)

---

Edit:

The following works for me but I think it is not optimal yet:

```
@Column('simple-json')
permissions: string[];
```

```
let user = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
  .where('user.permissions like :permissions', { permissions: `%"${UserPermission.SUPERADMIN}"%` })
  .getOne();
```

Comment: I dont know if theres a way to use Include function, in the edit fragment I suggest you to use Like() function, to prevent SQL Injections: { permissions: Like(`%${UserPermission.SUPERADMIN}%`).value}). Anyway would not be better to store user permissons in a separated table and then make the relationship?

Answer (score 14):

As Mykhalio mentioned , you can use the PostgreSQL array functions to do the trick.

Adding few more pointers.

1. If you want to check users with both USER_ADMIN and SUPER_ADMIN permissions.

> ```
> .where('user.permissions @> :permissions', { permissions:['USER_ADMIN', 'SUPER_ADMIN']})
> ```

2. If you want to check users with either USER_ADMIN or SUPER_ADMIN permissions.

> ```
> .where('user.permissions && :permissions', { permissions: ['USER_ADMIN', 'SUPER_ADMIN']})
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was looking for exactly the second "where" clause. That did the trick for me, awesome!

Answer (score 11):

Why not use this approach. Works for me with zero errors.

```
let roles = ['ADMIN', 'STUDENT', SECRETARY];
   let user = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
         .andWhere('user.roles IN (:...roles)')
        .setParameter('roles', ...roles).count()
```

Comment: can you tell why spread operator(...) is used with roles in setParameter and IN clause ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use PostgreSQL [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html)

```js
let user = await this.userRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .where('user.permissions @> ARRAY[:permissions]', { permissions: UserPermission.SUPERADMIN})
  .getOne();
```

Also, if you need to look for the presence of multiple array elements, you can use a spread operator (notice the `...`):

```
.where('user.permissions @> ARRAY[:...permissions]', { permissions: ['foo', 'bar']})
```

Comment: i am getting 'operator does not exist: text @> text[]' error

Answer (score 6):

it is also possible to search array values in your DB cell using [advanced find options](https://typeorm.io/find-options#advanced-options):

```
const found = await repo.findOne({
    where: {
      roles: ArrayContains([role]),
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this helper functions that implements the exact syntax that you expected

```
import { FindOperator, Raw } from 'typeorm';

export const Includes = <T extends string | number>(value: T): FindOperator<T> =>
    Raw((columnAlias) => `:value = ANY(${columnAlias})`, { value });
```