# Type mismatch at TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to search a cookieId within an array in Postgres using TypeORM.
The answer for this question is given here: [How do I query an array in TypeORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475174/how-do-i-query-an-array-in-typeorm/61259557#61259557)

However, when I implemeted the code:

```
user = await this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('user.userCookieIds @> ARRAY[:cookieId]', {cookieId: userCookieId})
      .getOne();
```

the relevant entity is:

```
@Column("varchar", { array: true })
  userCookieIds: string[];
```

I got an error:
`QueryFailedError: operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]`

How could I specify the type for `cookieId` in postgres in this case, so it would also be `varchar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cast the value to the correct type:

```
user = await this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('user.userCookieIds @> ARRAY[:cookieId]::varchar[]', {cookieId: userCookieId})
      .getOne();
```

You could also change your column to use a text array insead of a varchar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/735398